# transform XML nodeValue to PHP/HTML string

Tags: php, xml, string, transform, nodevalue

I am using AJAX live search to generate user-profile-specific links. It works well, I always end up at the profile I want to, but there ist an issue.

Let's do this for user 1 (username = testuser; user_id = 1; blogname = testblog). If I search for "test", both links will be displayed, the link to testuser's profile, and the link to testuser's blog. The strange thing now is, the links work as if they would look like this:

**profile.php?user=1&page=profile**

**profile.php?user=1&page=blog**

but the actual links look like this:

**profile.php?user=%20+%201%20+%20&page=profile**

**profile.php?user=%20+%201%20+%20&page=blog**

Since I end up on the page I want to, you could say it doesn't matter, but it does, because I need the $GET_['user'] values always to be real numbers, not that kind of stuff I'm dealing with, here.

I hope there is some easy way to fix this. Like nodeValue->string or something. I need to change the nodeValue in this part of the code I think: **$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue**

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("../xml/accounts.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('account');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {

    $hint="";

    for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
        $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('username');
        $b=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('blogname');
        $c=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('companyname');
        $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('user_id');



        //search for usernames
        if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {

            //find a link matching the search text
            if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {

                if ($hint=="") {
                    $hint=  "<a href='profile.php?user= + " . 
                        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
                        " + &page=profile' >" .
                        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a><span> (profile)</span>";

                } else {
                    $hint=  $hint . "<br /><a href='profile.php?user= + " .
                        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
                        " + &page=profile' >" .
                        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a><span> (profile)</span>";
                }
            }
        }




    //search for blognames
        if ($b->item(0)->nodeType==1) {

            //find a link matching the search text
            if (stristr($b->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {

                if ($hint=="") {
                    $hint=  "<a href='profile.php?user= + " . 
                        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
                        " + &page=blog' >" .
                        $b->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a><span> (blog)</span>";

                } else {
                    $hint=  $hint . "<br /><a href='profile.php?user= + " .
                        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
                        " + &page=blog' >" .
                        $b->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a><span> (blog)</span>";
                }
            }
        }


// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
    $response="no QuickResults, hit enter";
} else {
    $response=$hint;
}


//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Inside my **XMLfile** the structure looks like this, if it helps:

```
<account>
    <username>testuser</username>
    <user_id>1</user_id>
    <blogname>testblog</blogname>
</account>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are getting arises from the fact that your code adds spaces and a plus sign to the resulting link. And spaces are automatically encoded as `%20`. The solution would be to remove them from the code like this:

```
$hint=  "<a href='profile.php?user=" . 
         $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue .
         "&page=profile' >" .
         $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a><span> (profile)</span>";
```

This change would need to be done in all four occurences.

Comment: Done, and it works, thanks a lot for you help and letting me know :)

Comment: Happy to help. I would be glad if you could mark my post as an [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thanks!

Comment: for sure, i didn't even know about that ;)