# XML node Value format

Tags: php, xml, string, nodevalue

I'm getting the value of this element from my XML file:

```
<user_id>1</user_id>
```

and i always looks like this:

```
%20+%201%20+%20
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
1
```

How can such a thing happen? I don't even understand this transforming process. And how can I prevent that?

Thanks guys!

(this question is just a basic version to get some understanding. The full code and entire problem can be found in my question this morning:

[transform XML nodeValue to PHP/HTML string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036605/transform-xml-nodevalue-to-php-html-string))

Comment: `%20` probably equals to space. But without your code everything is just guessing.

Comment: this question is just a basic version to get some understanding. The full code and entire problem can be found in my question this morning:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036605/transform-xml-nodevalue-to-php-html-string

Comment: You are just putting the spaces and a plus sign from your own code: `"<a href='profile.php?user= + ".$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue ." + &page=blog' >"`. So remove the spaces and + sign following `?user` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. Everything is fine now :)

Comment: @JiriHrazdil: I guess you may post an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have posted the answer in the original thread. I'll flag this one so it gets closed/removed as duplicate.